# GWT RPC method name at App Engine server log

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc

our project runs on GWT and Java App Engine and we use the standard GWT RPC mechanism.
App engine adds log trace for each RPC call, but it just logs the servlet URL and not the called method.
We would like to add the **method name** to the log URL.

We have tried extending RpcRequestBuilder class, overriding doCreate and adding the method name to the URL, but the problem is that at this point the method name is unknown - it's known later at doSetRequestData (as part of the data string).

Thanks
Itzik

Answer (score 0):

In each rpc implementation you can override one of readContent and processCall and add logging.

```
@Override
public String processCall(String payload) throws SerializationException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String processCall = super.processCall(payload);
    Logger.getLogger("").info(processCall);
    return processCall;
}

@Override
protected String readContent(HttpServletRequest request)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String readContent = super.readContent(request);
    Logger.getLogger("").info(readContent);
    return readContent;
}
```

Log Line

> 6|0|4|http://127.0.0.1:8888/_4021625/|35C4974968FC8F8A9A7EA4881FD49F57|com.bitdual.client.LogMeService|logmemethod|1|2|3|4|0|

Comment: Thanks, we don't want to add any logging - just to add to the existing one (done by the app engine) the method name.

Comment: You'd end up with an additional line/detail record in the already existing entry. Is there a technical reason for this not working for your situation?